# netbeans 8 does not refer to the actual PHP file path, when running a PHP file

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have installed php, mysql and nginx properly.

I am able to run the PHP pages from Eclipse, i.e Eclipse opens up chrome, and pages are displayed correctly.

I imported my existing PHP project into Netbeans.

When I try to run any of the php pages, netbeans opens up chrome, but the web address is always the same, and not the real path of the PHP file.

Why netbeans refers to the same location, instead of trying to run the file from its real path? how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Qwerty

Comment: Can someone PLEASE assist...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The green "play" button in Netbeans does not run the current file, but runs the PROJECT! This caused eclipse to run the project path instead of the current file location!

Therefore, in order to run the current file click on "Run -> Run File" (Shift +F6), and then it works.

Just make sure that the project path is set properly in "Run->Set Project Configuration -> Customize", and then set the project URL to:

http://localhost/

That`s it!

Thanks,

Qwerty